# Is BBR congestion control available on my host or not

Tags: linux-networking, socket, linux-kernel

I have been looking into enabling [bbr congestion control](https://research.google/pubs/pub45646/) on some of our servers to test if they make any difference for our workloads.

We are on Amazon Linux 2:

```
# uname -a
Linux ip-10-1-66-180.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io 4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 1 18:06:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I had a look into available congestion control and got this

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control
cubic reno
```

Does this mean `bbr` support is not available in our kernel? I saw some people showing the same output of the above command and still setting `sysctl`s to `bbr` regardless.

I also checked the kernel modules as I've read somewhere that some `bbr` module needs to be loaded but I suspect that was necessary for older Kernels.

```
# lsmod | grep -i bbr
```

Is there a way I can enable `bbr` on our servers given the kernel version I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernels in Amazon Linux 2 do indeed include BBR congestion control support. You enable it like any other congestion control method.

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo bbr > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control 
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control 
bbr
```

Because it was built as a module it is loaded on demand, so it deos not show up as available unless the module had already been loaded. Now you can see it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control
bbr cubic reno
[root@localhost ~]# lsmod | grep -i bbr
tcp_bbr                20480  5
```